# How to block access to localhost from the Internet in Xampp?

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd

In my Apache config file `httpd.conf` I have:

```
...

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

...

<Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

...
```

I understand from looking this issue up that I should insert somewhere the following lines:

```
order allow,deny
allow from 127.0.0.1
deny from all
```

What I don't know is, exactly where in relation to what I already have in my config file. For example, what do I do with the line "Require all granted"? Do I delete it, or paste this snippet above it? Below it? What about the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only wanting to restrict access to the local system (i.e: you're not trying to understand the `Order` / `Allow` / `Deny` directives), then the following solution is sufficient and "*the correct solution*".

You should bind the socket to `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0` (which is used by default) - this way only the local system is able to connect, and the restriction is enforced at the socket / OS level, rather than within Apache.

To do this, use the [`Listen`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directive - for example, replace `Listen 80` with `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

> What do I do with the line `Require all granted`? Do I delete it, or paste this snippet above it? Below it? What about the rest?

The `order allow, deny` directives are old syntax and should be avoided as support for them may be removed in future versions of Apache. You should instead (for instance) replace `Require all granted` with ex. `Require ip 127.0.0.1`:

```
<Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs">
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

You can read a basic overview of managing access with the `Require` directive [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html).

> How do I block access to localhost from the internet in XAMPP?

As already mentioned in the other answer to this question, you may wish to consider binding your `httpd.conf` `Listen` directive to `127.0.0.1`:

*ex. httpd.conf*

```
# Listen 80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

*Caveats*:

- This will prevent any computer or device from your local network connecting as well. Only connections from `127.0.0.1` (the computer XAMPP is running on) will be allowed.
- This will not affect ex. HTTPS (port 443). You would need to specify this separately (under e.g. `\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf`) as `Listen 127.0.0.1:443`.

*The Better Option?*

If you are doing local development and aren't worried about other computers or devices on your local network accessing XAMPP, the simpler/better option may be just to not port forward internet connections from your router to XAMPP. Assuming you router isn't terrible, this should (ideally) prevent general access by anyone outside your local network.

Comment: Thank you :) The first answer was enough for my use case though so I had to accept it since it was also given earlier, I appreciate your time and effort though. Thanks again.

Comment: Not a problem. I genuinely appreciate it. =) For what it's worth, I upvoted the other answer myself. =P